# Application of the pigeon hole principle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

There's a problem in my textbook that I'm having difficulties understanding. The solution given skips steps and is hard to decipher. The problem is as follows:

"During a month with 30 days, a baseball team plays at least one game a day, but no more than 45 games. Show that there must be a period of some number of consecutive days during which the team must play exactly 14 games."

I don't know how to arrive at the conclusion of 14 games. Anyone who can help me understand this application of the pigeon-hole principle would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $\{a_i\}_{i = 0}^{30}$ denote the number of games up until and including the $i$-th day of the month (put $a_0 = 0$). Given the conditions of the task, $\{a_i\}$ is an increasing sequence with all members distinct and $0 \leq a_i \leq 45$.

Now, consider the sequence $\{a_i + 14\}_{i = 1}^{30}$ (add $14$ to every member of the original sequence). It is also increasing with all members distinct, but with $14 \leq a_i + 14 \leq 59$. Together these sequences consist of $62$ integers between $0$ and $59$, so by the pigeonhole principle, two of them must be equal.

Since both the sequences $\{a_i\}$ and $\{a_i + 14\}$ have distinct members, there must be indices $j$ and $k$ with $j \ne k$ such that $a_j = a_k + 14$. This means that 14 games were played in the period between the $(k + 1)$-st and the $j$-th day.

Comment: Shouldn't you also use $a_0=0$ and $a_0+14$? That would make $62$ integers between $0$ and $59$ of course, but your answer actually shows that we can always pick the desired period in a way that does not include the first day (your $k+1$ is always $\ge2$). Apparently, the problem statement allows a lot of leeway

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You are correct. I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: This means that 14 games were played in the period between the $(k+1)$-st and the $j$-th day. Can you please explain this part a little bit more?

Answer (score 9):

Let $f(n)$ be the number of games played within the first $n$ days. Then we know that $f(0)=0$, $f(30)\le 45$ and $f(k+1)\ge f(k)+1$ for $0\le k<30$. 
If we can find $0\le i<j\le 30$ with $f(j)=f(i)+14$, this means that on days $i+1,\ldots, j$ a total of $14$ games are played and we are done.

Let $g(k)$ be the remainder of $f(k)$ modulo $14$. Then one of the $14$ possible values must occur at least $3$ times because $2\cdot 14<31$. So there are numbers $0\le a<b<c\le 30$ with $g(a)=g(b)=g(c)$. Then $f(b)-f(a)$ and $f(c)-f(b)$ are both multiples of $14$ and are both positive. If neither of them equals $14$, then $f(c)-f(b)\ge 28$ and $f(b)-f(a)\ge 28$ so that $f(c)\ge 56+f(a)\ge56$, which is absurd. We conclude that $f(b)-f(a)=14$ or $f(c)-f(b)=14$ (or both).

*Remark:* The problem statement is not "tight" in the following sense: The above solution works also if we allow up to $55$ games during the month; or alternatively if we replaced $14$ with any number $\in\{12,\ldots,15\}$.

Comment: what if we say there are consecutive days with 11 games played or with 9 games played? why would it be inconsistent? Where comes the value of $\{12,\ldots 15\}$ or the value of $55$ as tight bound. Can you please explain?

Comment: and why did you use the argument $2.14 <31$ when June has $30$ days?

Comment: and if $\exists_{ij} a_i = a_j + 14$ why does it warrant that there was a span of consecutive days when 14 games were played?

Comment: Why the numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_{30}$ are distinct and increasing. I don't get that please?

Answer (score 4):

For $k=0$ through $30$ let $g_k$ be the total number of games played up through day $k$. Then

$$0=g_0<g_1<g_2<\ldots<g_{30}\le 45\;.$$

Now let $h_k=g_k+14$ for $k=0,\ldots,29$, so that

$$14=h_0<h_1<h_2<\ldots<h_{29}=g_{29}+14<g_{30}+14\le 45+14=59\;.$$

Note that $g_1\ge 1$, and $h_{29}\le 58$.

If we can find $k$ and $\ell$ such that $h_k=g_\ell$, we’re in business, because then $g_k+14=g_\ell$, meaning that $14$ games are played on days $k+1$ through $\ell$.

There are $30$ different numbers $h_0,\ldots,h_{29}$, all lying in the range from $14$ through $58$ inclusive, and $30$ different numbers $g_1,\ldots,g_{30}$, all lying in the range from $1$ through $45$ inclusive. Altogether, then, we have $60$ numbers in the range from $1$ through $58$, and the pigeonhole principle ensures that at least two of them must be the same. The numbers $h_k$ are all distinct, and the numbers $g_\ell$ are all distinct, so some $h_k$ must be equal to some $g_\ell$: there must be $k$ and $\ell$ such that $h_k=g_\ell$.

Comment: Actually, Brian, I realized my suggested edit also missed out on the case where k=0. Thank you for rejecting it and sorry for making an incomplete/incorrect suggestion.

Comment: @Deepak: No problem: I almost changed it to that myself before posting, until I realized that I needed $k=0$.

Comment: Why the numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_{30}$ are distinct and increasing. I don't get that please?

Comment: @Avra: There are no numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_{30}$ in my answer; do you mean $g_0,\ldots,g_{30}$? They are strictly increasing because for $k=1,\ldots,30$, $g_k-g_{k-1}$ is the number of games played on day $k$, and that is always at least $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you very much Mr. Brian. So, you mean the number of games accumulate over days? In day 1, they played one game. In day $i=2$, they played one more game plus game from previous day 1 would make up a total of 2 games, is that correct please? If that is the case, how  I can conclude that from the question that games are strictly distinct and increasing please?

Comment: I also don't get Mr. Brian how there are 14 games payed from day $ j+1$ to day $i$ in $g_i=g_j+14$? How are allowed anyway to add 14 given that total number of games is only 45 in the question please? Also I don't get where this period is? If it's from $j+1$ to $i$, what is $i$ in this case and what is $j$? Is this period one day only? Because from $i$ to $j+1$, we have 14 games played in one day period only as I understand.

Comment: @Avra: $g_k$ is the total number of games played on days $1$ through $k$. If they play one game on day $1$, two games on day $2$, one game on day $3$, and $11$ games on day $4$, for instance, then $g_1=1$, $g_2=1+2=3$, $g_3=1+2+1=4$, and $g_4=1+2+1+11=15$. Notice that $g_4=g_1+14$. $g_4$ is the total number of games played in the first $4$ days, and $g_1$ is the number played the first day, so $g_4-g_1$ is the total number played on days $2,3$, and $4$. And $g_4-g_1=14$, so exactly $14$ games were played during that three-day period. In this example $j=1$ and $i=4$, and days $j+1$ through ...

Comment: ... $i$ are days $2,3$, and $4$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thanks!

Comment: @Avra: You’re welcome!